# Postgres Returning Incorrect Data Type for Specific Column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm in the process of creating two tables. One is a staging place for data that will be inserted into the target table.

```
CREATE TABLE test.table1 (
    welcome_call_completed_date timestamp without time zone null,
    test_date                   timestamp without time zone null,
    character_field             varchar                     null
);

CREATE TABLE staging.table1 (
    welcome_call_completed_date timestamp without time zone null,
    test_date                   timestamp without time zone null,
    character_field             varchar                     null
);
```

When I select just `welcome_call_completed_date` from `test.table1`, postgres returns no results with column type `timestamp` as expected. When I select it from `staging.table1` postgres returns type `text` with no results. This problem doesn't happen with the other two fields, I created the test_date field just to test that out and in both tables it returns the correct type.

When I look in the `information_schema.columns` view, I can see both `welcome_call_completed_date` columns in both tables listed as `timestamp without time zone`. The problem seems to be isolated to the `staging` schema, but even when I drop the whole `staging` schema and recreate it, the problem persists.  When I create the table in another schema and even another database and server, the column returns the correct type.

Dropping and re-creating the schema/table/column doesn't seem to fix the issue, even running an `ALTER` statement to correct the column type doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea what's happening here and how to fix it??

The queries I'm using are very simple:

- Query 1:

  - ```
    SELECT welcome_call_completed_date FROM test.table1
    ```

    Returns [image: this]
- Query 2:

  - ```
    SELECT welcome_call_completed_date FROM staging.table1
    ```

    Returns [image: this]

---

- You can see the data type being returned by DBeaver here next to the column name.
- The `text` data type here can also be confirmed when I'm trying to insert data into the test table from the staging table using psycopg2.

> [image]
>
> `psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch:` column `welcome_call_completed_date` is of type `timestamp without time zone` but expression is of type `text`.

The SQL I'm running here is:

```
INSERT INTO test.table1 ( welcome_call_completed_date ) 
SELECT
    welcome_call_completed_date
FROM
    staging.table1
```

I was able to get around this issue by creating a new schema called `stage` and creating my staging table there instead, but I'm still curious as to why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: How do you determine the returned type?

Comment: **Update your question with the following**: 1) The queries you are using to select from the tables to your question. 2) The results(or at least an partial example) from the queries. 3) Postgres version 4) In `psql` what if anything is returned by `\dT *.welcome_call_completed_date`.

Comment: Updated with the requested information!

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you're seeing when I use DBFiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ubhFJhoXc874ipRzf8aLVU/0

Comment: That's the weird part, this doesn't happen in any other db I've tried it in. All I can think is that maybe Postgres has a cached version of the table somewhere in it's memory that it's referring to when I drop and create the `staging.table1` and `staging` schema

Comment: 1) Don't trust DBeaver to tell you the truth, I have seen too many cases here where it is not. 2) Use `psql` and do `\d staging.table1` for the table definition. 3) While you are there do `\dT *.welcome_call_completed_date`.

Comment: A thought, in `psql` do `\d *."staging.table1"`.

Comment: I didn't trust DBeaver to tell me this, it was further confirmation when trying to move data from one table to the other that the type in the `staging` table was incorrectly text, even though the `information_schema` and create statement say differently.

Comment: Have you run the `\d` commands ?

Comment: @Tom I had a very similar situation myself (SQL Server, with two "_identical_" tables in different schemas, but when using ODBC/OLEDB/ADO.NET to `SELECT etc FROM etc` and looking at the column metadata showed that seemingly identical columns were reported as having different data-types and `NOT NULL`/`NULL` - anyway, long story short it was because I had a _third table_ in a third schema which was almost _homoglyphically_ identical to one of the others (think: `deml` vs `demI`, or `db1` vs `dbi`, yaknow...)